# C Increase char array of char array size

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, realloc

I have a char array of char array like so:

```
char my_test[2][10];
```

As you can see I have a length of 2 and then 10. If I need to increase the first char array (2), how can this be done dynamically?

For example, half way through my application char[2] might be in use so therefore I need to use position 3 in the char array. I would then end up with this:

```
char store[3][10];
```

But keeping the data originally store in:

```
char store[0][10];
char store[1][10];
char store[2][10];
```

Comment: Named arrays cannot be resized in C. You will need to use the `malloc` and `realloc` functions to create a resizeable array.

Comment: In C, "I need to increase the first char array", is a false premise.  Instead, create a pointer to data and later increase the memory's allocation with `realloc()`.

Comment: "*As you can see I have a length of 2 and then 10.*" -- **NO!** You have an array of `2` `10` character arrays. A 2D array is an *array of arrays*. Here, you have and array of 2 - 10-char arrays. Arrays cannot be resized. Blocks of memory can. You can declare `char (*my_test)[10];` to create a pointer to an array of 10-chars and then allocate/reallocate the number of 10-char arrays in that block. Or, you can decalre `char **my_test;` and allocate and reallocate each individual block each pointer points to.

Comment: Ok. I did say I'm a beginner and learning C, I have read about pointers but they confuse the hell out of me. Does anyone have a really newbie way of explaining them?

Comment: Pointers are simply variables that hold the *address of* something else as their value. (a pointer *points* to where in memory a value is found) So where `int a = 5;` (`a` holds the immediate value `5` as its value), `int *b;` declares a pointer to type `int`. Meaning it will hold the address of where an integer is stored as its value. (e.g. `b = &a;`) would assign the address where `a` is stored to the pointer `b`). Nothing else special about them.

Comment: Thanks David C. I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dynamically allocate memory for the array using standard C functions `malloc` and `realloc` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the memory can be allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 2;
    char ( *my_test )[N] = malloc( n * sizeof( char[N] ) );

    strcpy( my_test[0], "first" );
    strcpy( my_test[1], "second" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( my_test[i] );

    putchar( '\n' );

    char ( *tmp )[N] = realloc( my_test, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char[N] ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        my_test = tmp;
        strcpy( my_test[n++], "third" );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( my_test[i] );

    free( my_test );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
first
second

first
second
third
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char my_test[2][10];
```

is compile-time constant, which means that the required memory to use that array is carved to the stone already before your application starts. So you will never be able to change it's size.

You'll have to use DYNAMIC allocation. Check for something called **malloc** and **free** in case you are really working with C, or with C++ **new** and **delete** are what you need. You'll also need to learn about pointers.